# Oh My Zsh multiple commands with one alias

Tags: customization, zsh, bash, oh-my-zsh

I'm using [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), and was wondering if there is a way to create a function or alias to run multiple commands. Just as an example, running an 'update' command will update specific gems, but not all of them.

Comment: Figured it out alias name="something; something else"

Answer (score 80, accepted):

As you've discovered, you can chain commands in a single alias using `;`:

```
alias update_my_gems="echo foo; echo bar"
```

Alternatively, you can write a function very easily in your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
update_my_gems() {
    echo foo
    echo bar
}
```

For readability, I'd personally go for a function for anything that's semi-complex.

Comment: I'd default to using a function for *anything*, unless there is a reason why an alias is better (which will rarely be the case).

Comment: I ended up making a function exactly like that. Thank you!

Comment: @snakesonatoni, do you know of an effective way to replace an OMZ alias with one that accepts parameters? I haven't had much luck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61109665/ohmyzsh-override-git-plugin-aliases-with-custom-multi-line-aliases-functions

Answer (score 2):

If there are many commands, I find it useful to alias the execution of a .sh file located on my home directory

```
alias start_containers="./start-containers.sh"
```

To throw the alias inside the config file, you can do

```
echo alias start_containers="./start-containers.sh" >> ~/.zshrc
```