# Simple Multi-Line Command Function alias in .zshrc

Tags: git, zsh

I am trying to write a command which commit's to the origin master for github, and on completion of that, shut's down the computer... Here is what I have, and it is pointing out a lot of syntax errors as I cannot find out how to have a multiline alias command... Thanks a lot and below is my function, apologies if this is a basic mistake as I am relatively new to the ZSH shell.

```
# Push to origin master and shut down
alias gitshut=
'
git add .;
git commit -m "Latest Commit";
git push -f origin master;
'
```

Thanks again, and i appreciate your help

Comment: I know what is an _alias_, but what is a _**command function** alias_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't bother with an alias at all. Define a function.

```
gitshut () {
  git add .
  git commit -m "Latest Commit"
  git push -f origin master
}
```

Aside from having fewer quoting issues, this allows you to pass a better commit message as an argument, e.g.,

```
gitshut () {
  msg=${1:-Latest Commit}
  git add .
  git commit -m "$msg"
  git push -f origin master
}
```

Now you can use `gitshut` to use the default `Latest Commit` message, or `gitshut "Fixed overflow bug"` to provide something that actually describes what is being committed.

Answer (score 1):

Your alias does not address the shutdown part, but you could rewrite it with:

```
alias gitshut='git add .;git commit -m "Latest Commit";git push -f origin master;'
```

Or possibly as:

```
alias gitshut='\
   git add .;\
   git commit -m "Latest Commit";\
   git push -f origin master;'
```

Using a [function as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19264761/6309) might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your command first defined an empty alias named `gitshut`. This is what the line

```
alias gitshut=
```

is doing. After this, you asked zsh run a command with the funny name `\ngit add .;\ngit commit -m "Latest Commit";\ngit push -f origin master;\n` (where the \n represent newline characters). Since such a file does not exist, you get an error message (likely *zsh: command not found ....*).

You could write it as

```
alias='git add .
  git commit -m "Latest Commit"
  git push -f origin master'
```

but honestly, doing it as a function introduces you more flexibility (for instance introducing an optional parameter which goes into the commit message).

Comment: Thanks, I wrote it as a function, and it turned out to be really simple!!